# Tkinter Tix Checklist Hlist Header Configuration Options

Tags: python, tkinter, checklistbox, hlist, tix

I'm hoping a tcl/tk expert can help answer this super-niche question regarding a **Tix CheckList Hlist Header**.  All I want to do is change the background color from an ugly gray to white.

I find it very difficult to even know what options (`cnf={}` or `**kw`) I can use for ANYTHING in tix. I have discovered that I can do `self.checklist.hlist.config().keys()` which returns:

```
['background', 'bd', 'bg', 'borderwidth', 'browsecmd', 'columns', 'command',
 'cursor', 'dragcmd', 'drawbranch', 'dropcmd', 'fg', 'font', 'foreground',
 'gap', 'header', 'height', 'highlightbackground', 'highlightcolor',
 'highlightthickness', 'indent', 'indicator', 'indicatorcmd', 'itemtype',
 'padx', 'pady', 'relief', 'selectbackground', 'selectborderwidth',
 'selectforeground', 'selectmode', 'separator', 'sizecmd', 'takefocus',
 'wideselection', 'width', 'xscrollcommand', 'yscrollcommand']
```

I don't know how to do this for the **actual header object** to see what options are available.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Tix CheckList Hlist Header]

Here's the code that creates it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tix

class whatever(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(whatever, self).__init__(parent)
    self.parent = parent

    self.checklist = tix.CheckList(self.parent, browsecmd=self.selectItem,
                                   options='hlist.columns 1', highlightthickness=1,
                                   highlightcolor='#B7D9ED')
    self.checklist.grid(sticky='ew', padx=20)

    self.checklist.hlist.config(bg='white', bd=0, selectmode='none', selectbackground='white',
                                selectforeground='black', drawbranch=True, pady=5, header=True)

    self.checklist.hlist.header_create(0, itemtype=tix.TEXT, text='My Heading Text',
                                       relief='flat')

    self.checklist.hlist.add("CL1", text="checklist1")
    self.checklist.hlist.add("CL1.Item1", text="subitem1")
    self.checklist.setstatus("CL1", "on")
    self.checklist.setstatus("CL1.Item1", "off")

  def selectItem(self, item):
      print(item)

root = tix.Tk()
whatever(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Additional info**:

By the way, I'm mainly using this site to figure out what methods are available for `hlist` - http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tix.HList-class.html

This example was helpful too: https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Demo/tix/samples/SHList2.py

**What Have I Tried...**

Lots of things for hours on-end. I think this should be in:

```
self.checklist.hlist.header_configure(0, background='white')
```

but I've tried: `background`, `selectbackground`, `bg`, `color` ... and more. They all end with the same `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-NAMEHERE"`message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, add `headerbackground` parameter to `header_create()` method:

```
...
self.checklist.hlist.header_create(0, itemtype=tix.TEXT, text='My Heading Text', 
headerbackground="red", relief='flat')
...
```

Comment: I would have swore up and down that I tried that. Obviously not! Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy! Seems so obvious now.

Comment: I'm very curious, did you find this in documentation or did you do something to see what configuration options were available? Just curious for the future.